# Cut one hour from current time

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to display the current time.

```
(new Date()).toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3");
```

But I want to show the same time, but one hour ago. I just need to subtract 1 from the current hour.  How can I adjust this code to accomplish this?

I tried:

> (new Date()+" - 1
>   hour").toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/,
>   "$1$3");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
(new Date(new Date - 3600000)).toLocaleTimeString()
    .replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3");
```

There are `3600000` ms in one hour.

Comment: @Jigberto That's the same thing the calculation in adamb's answer is doing, for what it's worth -- 1000 ms per second, times 60 seconds in a minute, times 60 minutes in an hour.

Comment: @JimDagg Yes, it is. I submitted my answer a split second after adamb did.

Comment: @AaditMShah I see that, no sweat there.  Just wanted to help explain where the number 3600000 came from.  :)

Comment: @JimDagg That's the reason I explained that there are `3600000` ms in one hour.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1000*60*60))
```

Should do the trick.